# Can esxi hot add memory using vim-cmd?

Tags: vmware-esxi, memory

I've got HotAdd set to true and a bit less memory than I wanted allocated to a VM.  I've got this in the vmx file:

> memsize = "192"
>
> mem.hotadd = "TRUE"

But, I've cut out my legs to get on the vcenter console of this esxi server (barring lots of port forwards), is there a way to change the memory size with vim-cmd.  I didn't see anything obvious, I think I can edit the vmx file and restart the vm, but since I'm logged on to the console of the esxi server through the VM, I don't really want to do that!

So, is there a way to change memory or "hot reload" settings using vim-cmd?

Comment: A) no there's not and B) why are you trying to do this via the host console and not PowerCLI or one of the other supported APIs? or the GUI

Comment: @chopper3, the hypervisor is not addressed on the network and the only way to get to it is through one of the VMs it resides on.  
I can spin up another VM to connect to the esxi and do my work so I don't cut my legs off, but that requires a lot more work.

Comment: How come you can't get to the management network of the host? that sounds overly complex

Comment: @chopper, probably is a trade secret (definitely not my idea), but yes, it is overly complex - pretty secure though!

Comment: `pretty secure though!`, I think your keyboard is broken, because I'm certain you meant to write `pretty unusable too!`...

Comment: @gregl we used to have 'em in vcenter, but we're transitioning off of esxi so now they're in a fairly crappy state.  So yeah, pretty unusable - sucks, but it's temporary.